# Utilizing the two devices in a Tesla K80 on AWS p2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cuda

I use a p2 instance on AWS, that is supposed to have a Tesla K80 gpu, with two GK210 GPUs inside it (https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2014/11/18/tesla-k80-perf/).

According to the following post from Nvidia forums, I should be able to see and access each of the two devices separately (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/995255/using-tesla-k80-as-two-tesla-k40/?offset=4).

However, when I run nvidia-smi on the p2 instance, I only see one device:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-73 caffe]$ nvidia-smi
Wed Feb 22 12:20:51 2017
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.99     Driver Version: 352.99         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           On   | 0000:00:1E.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P8    31W / 149W |     55MiB / 11519MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I monitor and access the 2 devices?

Comment: One would assume that your assumption that you have two devices available is  incorrect. But this isn't AWS support, your question isn't really a programming related question, and probably should not have been asked here

Comment: When you discussed this with the NVIDIA forums, you made no mention of the AWS usage.  On AWS, the p2 instance in question has only 1/2 of a K80 GPU.  [This AWS blog article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-p2-instance-type-for-amazon-ec2-up-to-16-gpus/) covers the details.  The p2.xlarge instance has only a single GPU (which is referring to devices here, not GPU as a whole), and it has 2496 cores and 12GB of memory.  That is clearly 1/2 of a K80 GPU.  You may want to read that blog article carefully.

Comment: You even stated in that NVIDIA forum dialog this "If nvidia-smi gives me a list of four K80, it means I have two of them".  So it seems clear you understood the relationship/ratio.  A very direct extension of your statement would be "If nvidia-smi gives me a list of one K80, it means I have one-half of them", which would be an accurate statement here.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella! I did not write the post in the Nvidia forum - it's a post by someone else that I read in order to understand the issue. I read the AWS blog article that you refer to, it didn't say explicitly that the GPU on P2 is 1/2 of a K80 GPU. Do you just deduce it from the memory and core specs there?

Comment: Start reading the blog article again.  Read starting at the section titled "New P2 Instance Type".  You can stop reading after the first sentence in that section.  Then put that first sentence together with the chart, that shows 3 types, containing 1, 8, or 16 GPUs.  The 16 GPU instance must contain 8 K80 Accelerators, since that is the max listed in the first sentence.  The 8 GPU instance then contains 4 K80 Accelerators.  The instance with only 1 GPU must contain 1/2 of a K80 accelerator. You can also deduce it from the core and memory specs (which correspond to 1/2 of the K80 totals).

Answer (score 4):

The [actual situation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-p2-instance-type-for-amazon-ec2-up-to-16-gpus/) with a p2.xlarge instance is that you have 1/2 of a K80 assigned to that VM, so your `nvidia-smi` output here is expected, and you will not be able to access 2 GPU *devices* from that VM/instance type.